# Is there a way to find the users folder name in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code that I use to create a directory, but I want it to be able to go into anyone's folder, obviously. For example instead of ksmith I'd want it to find someone's jlaw. Is there something in objective c that does that?

```
strcpy(applicationPath, "/Users/ksmith/ApplicationCode");
strcpy(filesPath, "/Users/ksmith/ApplicationData");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the path to the current user’s home directory with the function

```
NSHomeDirectory()
```

For more information and related functions: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory).